# Faster way to recalculate maximum distance in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

Assume you are given a weighted directed graph *G* = (*V*, *E*) with *n* nodes, *p* of which are central. Let *C*, |*C*| = *p*  be the set of central nodes and *N* = *V* \ *C* be the set of non-central nodes. The value of edge *e*<sub>*ij*</sub> is finite non-negative real number if:

1. *i* is from the set *N*, while *j* is from the set *P*, or
2. *i* is from the set *P*, while *j* is from the set *P*, or
3. *i* is from the set *P*, while *j* is from the set *N*.

Otherwise, if *i* is from the set *N* and *j* is from the set *N*, value of *e*<sub>*ij*</sub> is equal to positive infinity.

We are interested in finding maximum over all shortest distances in graph *G*. The fastest algorithm I found to solve this is using a simple modification of Floyd-Warshall's algorithm, which runs in *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>*p*). Here is the simple pseudo-code:

```
FOR ALL k FROM the set C DO
  FOR ALL i FROM the set V DO
    FOR ALL j FROM the set V DO 
      e[i, j] = MIN(e[i, j], e[i, k] + e[k, j])
-----------------------------------------------
result = 0
FOR ALL i FROM the set V DO
  FOR ALL j FROM the set V DO
    result = MAX(result, e[i, j])
-----------------------------------------------
RETURN result
```

Probably, there is no faster algorithm than that. (Or, am I wrong? :))

However, I'm more interested in the following, and I think there is something faster here. Assume that we simply exchange two nodes from the sets *C* and *N*, ie. for some *v*<sub>*c*</sub> from *C* and some *v*<sub>*n*</sub> from *N*, the set *C* becomes *C* + *v*<sub>*n*</sub> - *v*<sub>*c*</sub> and set *N* becomes *N* + *v*<sub>*c*</sub> - *v*<sub>*n*</sub>.  Now, we are interesting in finding new maximum distance over all shortest distances in *G*.

The faster algorithm I know is simply to calculate from the beginning new maximum distance using described Floyd-Warshall's method, which runs again in *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>*p*). Is there any faster method for calculating this that probably uses the old calculated values of shortest distances before exchanging nodes?